# How To Remove Table border or hid to show my page

Tags: views

I made a view and display " tender" and the Page Format is Table and I don't want show the table border how to hide or remove?

Comment: You need to hide it with CSS

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your theme CSS:

```
table {border: none;}
```

Which will alter all the tables in your theme
To limit the border removal to just this view, find the view class [in Google chrome, use the code inspector] to find the div with the class 'view' and select the class appropriate to this view.
For example if you have the classes:

```
view
view-Tender
view-display-id-page_1
```

you can limit the table border css by:

```
.view-Tender table {border: none;}
```

for all the displays in the view or

```
.view-Tender.view-display-id-page_1 table {border: none;}
```

for just this display.